# passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_label_set_selectable’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, eclipse, gtk, label, warnings

I trying to learn GTK programming. I wrote a simple program in c. I am trying to pass a pointer to a label to the gtk_label_set_selectable() function, but I get this warning:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long i = 1;

void showadd(short u,GtkWidget *l)
{
    char * s;
    s = (char*)malloc(20);
    sprintf(s,"%ld",++i);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(l),s);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    GtkWidget * win,* lable, * addButton,* SubstractButton,*box;

    win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    addButton = gtk_button_new_with_label("+");
    lable = gtk_label_new("1");
    box = gtk_vbox_new(0,0);

    g_signal_connect(win,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(exit),NULL);
    g_signal_connect(addButton,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(showadd),(gpointer)lable);
    gtk_label_set_selectable(lable,1); //getting warring here

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win),box);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box),lable,1,0,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box),addButton,1,0,0);
    gtk_widget_show_all(win);

    gtk_main();
}
```

Whene I compile this in eclipse CDT I get this warning in the console :

```
../src/Calculator.c:35:28: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_label_set_selectable’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   gtk_label_set_selectable(lable,1);
                            ^~~~~
```

Should I ignore this warning? If not then what can I do to make it go away? And if yes then how can I make disappear in eclipse.

Comment: It expects a `GtkLabel *`, and you're passing it a `GtkWidget *`.  The compiler is letting you know you made a mistake.  Change it to pass a `GtkLabel *`.

Comment: Tom means to declare it as `GtkLabel *lable;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GTK you need to take care about the types of your widgets.

Normally only `GtkWidget*` is used instead of more specialized types because the `gtk_*_new()` functions also return a pointer to `GtkWidget` instead of `GtkLabel` etc.

To use a `GtkWidget*` in a function expecting a `GtkLabel*` you need to cast using `GTK_LABEL(label)`.

This is the mechanism you're already using when you call `GTK_CONTAINER()` and `GTK_BOX()`.